# What should I consider for a live concert recording device?

Tags: microphone

I am a hobbyist archivist who likes to record concerts for the internet archives. I used to use a small battery powered device that recorded audio at cd quality of 44.1KHz/16-bit. This device was excellent for certain kinds of concerts like live orchestral performances, but it was terrible for loud rock concerts. I was able to adjust the gain and low end cutoff, but it was still overwhelmed in louder environments.. it maybe exceeded the acoustic overload. It’s also broken now so I’ll need a replacement.

I haven’t been able to find a suitable alternative, so I am considering making one. Using a sufficient microcontroller, I’m hoping to sample at 44.1KHz/16-bit so I’ll need at least a 16-bit ADC…

What I’m not sure about is the microphone. Ideally, it wouldn’t be too large nor power hungry. Something the size of a fingernail or smaller. I want it to have a good spectrum response 20Hz-20KHz without excessive distortion at louder volumes.

Looking on parts suppliers, I can find plenty of small cheap microphones. Most have around 3% total harmonic distortion of 1Khz at 115dB SPL. This seems tolerable but maybe not ideal for playback? Acoustic overload at 115dB also seems maybe too low.

Comment: a side question: you're combining electronics hobby with music hobby? Because I'm no expert, but I think you can find a million devices on the market that can record stuff in good quality

Comment: Are you doing an official recording with permission from the artist / group?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't see that that's relevant. We're not the police.

Comment: @Ilya I have tried a few off the shelf solutions, but they have some limitations like saving into lossy formats only, distortion at high volumes, no gain control, high prices.. I found it easier to just make my own solution when it comes to audio or music/midi..

Comment: @IanBland but getting access to a quality live feed may be useful and easier . Not sure the police have access to a live feed -unless you mean the band …

Comment: @ShawnS maybe try multiple recording circuits with different properties that you can later master into proper better quality audio then?

Comment: Shopping questions aren't allowed on the site and yours is close to crossing the line so it has attracted some close votes. I suggest that you edit to make it a definite technical question without any question of product recommendation.

Comment: @Solar Mike For the next recording, yes. Though if it ever was a problem, it can be reported / taken down on archives.

Comment: It's against the rules here to recommend having at least a look at the Sony PCM-M10 as a sound recorder, so I won't do that.

Comment: If you have not found gear that can store as lossless formats and has mics or external inputs to connect external mics that can handle the sound pressure then you have not done much research. Which also indicates the assumption that making your own from scratch is a viable option may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you go building a sampling DAC etc, you should do some testing of microphones because that is where the problem will be that you've experienced before. You need to design your preamp circuit to fit to the voltages generated by those high SPLs.

Maybe then an analogue solution involving a suitable microphone and preamp into a commercial recording device might be a way forward?